# Can't figure how phone number reveal works

Tags: web-scraping

I am pretty new to web-scraping and recently I am trying to automatically scrap phone number for pages like [this](https://www.gumtree.com/p/vans/2015-ford-transit-custom-2.2tdci-290-l1-h1/1190345514). I am not supposed to use Selenium/headless url browser libraries and I am trying to find the a way to actually request the phone number using let say a web service or any other possible solution that could give me the phone number hopefully directly without having to go through the actual button press by selenium.

I totally understand that it may not even be possible to automatically reveal the phone number in one shut as it is meant not be accessible by nosy newbie web-scraper like me; but I still like to raise the question for my information to get detailed answer from an expert point of view.

If I search the "Reveal" button DOM element, it shows some tags which I have never seen before. I have two main questions which I believe could be helpful for newbies like me.

1) Given a set of unknown tags/attribues (ie. data-q and data-reveal in the blow button), how is one able to find out which scripts in the page are actually using them?

2) I googled the button element's tag like: data-q and data-reveal the only relevant I could find was [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjL8cmOh8zPAhXh4IMKHdkGC1gQFgghMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com.hcs.world%2Fquestions%2F37600948%2Fphp-curl-script-need-to-click-reveal-button&usg=AFQjCNEwcrmNB21eCRtbK_cQ_RJPc0p4rw&sig2=3X3CZsbfum45BwqqP4rswg&bvm=bv.135258522,d.amc&cad=rja) which for some reason I don't have access two even-if I use proxy.

Any clue particularly on the first question is much appreciate it.

Regards,

## Below is the href-button code

```
<a href="#" class="btn-secondary set-right is-disabled" data-q="reply-panel-reveal-btn" data-reveal="advertId:1190345514" data-analytics="gaEvent:R2SPhoneBegin,zenoEvent:PhoneEvent,zenoOptions:{adId:1190345514,pageType:VIP}" data-toggler="channel:syi.reveal-phone,className:is-disabled,selfBroadcast:false" aria-expanded="true">Reveal</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, according to your demand there are several steps before you finally get a solution.

1st step : open your own browser and enter your target page(https://www.gumtree.com/p/vans/2015-ford-transit-custom-2.2tdci-290-l1-h1/1190345514)

2nd step : (Assume you are using Chrome as your favorite browser) Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to open the console, and then select 'Network' tag in the console.

3rd step : Press the 'Reveal' button on that page, watch the console carefully, catch the http request which is sent immediately when you press the 'Reveal' button. You can see the request contains a long string of number in Query String Parameters, actually it is a timestamp.

4th step : Also you can see there is a part named 'Request Headers' in that http request, and you should copy the values of referer , user-agent , x-gumtree-token.

5th step : Try to construct your request (I am a fan of Python, So I am going to show you my example code in Python)

```
import time
import requests
import json

headers = {
        'referer': 'please enter the value you just copied from that specific request',
        'user-agent': 'please enter the value you just copied from that specific request',
        'x-gumtree-token': 'please enter the value you just copied from that specific request'
    }

url = 'https://www.gumtree.com/ajax/account/seller/reveal/number/1190345514?_='

current_time = time.time()
current_time = str(current_time)
current_time = current_time.split('.')[0] + current_time.split('.')[1] + '0'
url += current_time
response = requests.get(url=url,headers=headers)
response_result = json.loads(response.content)
phone_number = response_result['data']
```